# How to define that a return type of method is an implementation of superclass

Tags: python

Taking the code below for example:

```py
from random import shuffle

class _Launcher:
    pass

class ImplLaucher1(_Launcher):
    pass

class ImplLauncher2(_Launcher):
    pass

def get_launch_impl():
    launcher_implementations = [ImplLaucher1, ImplLauncher2]
    shuffle(launcher_implementations)
    return launcher_implementations[0]
```

How can I define the return type of `get_launch_impl()` considering that every return value will be a subclass of `_Launcher`?

I've tried simply `get_launch_impl() -> _Launcher` but I get an error saying that `_Launcher` object was expected to be returned.

Comment: `-> _Launcher` is the correct annotation. The problem is that you returned the class, not an instance of it. Try `return launcher_implementations[0]()`.

Comment: @kaya3 The function is supposed to return a class, not an instance of the class. The question is how to create a type hint that expresses that. (At least, I assume that "implementation" here refers to a class that subclasses an otherwise abstract class, not an instantiation of a class.)

Comment: @chepner The title says its return *type* is a class, which means the value should be an instance.

Comment: It doesn't say that. It says the "return type ... is an implemenation of a superclass". "Implementation" usually refers to a class that defines the methods of an abstract base class. The question itself is quite clear that the "return value will be a subclass of `_Launcher`", not an *instance* of `_Launcher`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).

```
from typing import Type


def get_launch_impl() -> Type[_Launcher]:
    ...
```